# Chrome does not load the new updated image

Tags: jquery, html, image, google-chrome

I've a problem with Chrome : i've a page with products that is use Galleryffic (jquery plugin) and i've updated the second element of gallery with a new image.

In Mozilla Firefox, IE6+, Safari 3+ they show the updated image,but in chrome version 19.0.1084.46 m , it shows the old image.

I tried to cancel and re-add the image,Ctrl+f5 , delete history,cookies,cache :
nothing to do, Chrome show the old image even if the image has been deleted.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the image in the file system or within the cache? I assume it's a cache problem, maybe inside the plugin itself. Try looking in the resource tab of your Chrome Developer Tools and look for the image resource, change timestamp and the image location itself.

Comment: It sure sounds like a caching issue, but you'll have to show us a working/non-working page where we can see the issue in order to know what to suggest.

Comment: [ctrl]+[shit]+[del] --> Choose (the begining of time) and tick in front of (Empty the cache) --> Click (Clear browsing data) button

Answer (score 1):

delete your complete history via ctrl + shift + del and then update your browser this problem is old version of google chrome.